# Google Places API Autocomplete get cities List only

Tags: android, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am implementing google's places autocomplete on my Android app and it is working which show every similar places, but how can I get cities suggestions only when user tries to search anything.

I have searched alot I was unable to find similar problems for Android places autocomplete.

I have implemented PlaceAutocompleteAdapter from google's example and this how it looks like

> PlaceAutocompleteAdapter

```
package com.tribikram.smartcitytraveler;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.style.CharacterStyle;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataBufferUtils;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

/**
 * Adapter that handles Autocomplete requests from the Places Geo Data Client.
 * {@link AutocompletePrediction} results from the API are frozen and stored directly in this
 * adapter. (See {@link AutocompletePrediction#freeze()}.)
 */
public class PlaceAutocompleteAdapter
        extends ArrayAdapter<AutocompletePrediction> implements Filterable {

    private static final String TAG = "PlaceACA";
    private static final CharacterStyle STYLE_BOLD = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
    /**
     * Current results returned by this adapter.
     */
    private ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> mResultList;

    /**
     * Handles autocomplete requests.
     */
    private GeoDataClient mGeoDataClient;

    /**
     * The bounds used for Places Geo Data autocomplete API requests.
     */
    private LatLngBounds mBounds;

    /**
     * The autocomplete filter used to restrict queries to a specific set of place types.
     */
    private AutocompleteFilter mPlaceFilter;

    /**
     * Initializes with a resource for text rows and autocomplete query bounds.
     *
     * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int)
     */
    public PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, GeoDataClient geoDataClient,
                                    LatLngBounds bounds, AutocompleteFilter filter) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1);
        mGeoDataClient = geoDataClient;
        mBounds = bounds;
        mPlaceFilter = filter;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the bounds for all subsequent queries.
     */
    public void setBounds(LatLngBounds bounds) {
        mBounds = bounds;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of results received in the last autocomplete query.
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResultList.size();
    }

    /**
     * Returns an item from the last autocomplete query.
     */
    @Override
    public AutocompletePrediction getItem(int position) {
        return mResultList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // Sets the primary and secondary text for a row.
        // Note that getPrimaryText() and getSecondaryText() return a CharSequence that may contain
        // styling based on the given CharacterStyle.

        AutocompletePrediction item = getItem(position);

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        textView1.setText(item.getPrimaryText(STYLE_BOLD));
        textView2.setText(item.getSecondaryText(STYLE_BOLD));

        return row;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the filter for the current set of autocomplete results.
     */
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                // We need a separate list to store the results, since
                // this is run asynchronously.
                ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> filterData = new ArrayList<>();

                // Skip the autocomplete query if no constraints are given.
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Query the autocomplete API for the (constraint) search string.
                    filterData = getAutocomplete(constraint);
                }

                results.values = filterData;
                if (filterData != null) {
                    results.count = filterData.size();
                } else {
                    results.count = 0;
                }

                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                    mResultList = (ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                // Override this method to display a readable result in the AutocompleteTextView
                // when clicked.
                if (resultValue instanceof AutocompletePrediction) {
                    return ((AutocompletePrediction) resultValue).getFullText(null);
                } else {
                    return super.convertResultToString(resultValue);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Submits an autocomplete query to the Places Geo Data Autocomplete API.
     * Results are returned as frozen AutocompletePrediction objects, ready to be cached.
     * Returns an empty list if no results were found.
     * Returns null if the API client is not available or the query did not complete
     * successfully.
     * This method MUST be called off the main UI thread, as it will block until data is returned
     * from the API, which may include a network request.
     *
     * @param constraint Autocomplete query string
     * @return Results from the autocomplete API or null if the query was not successful.
     * @see GeoDataClient#getAutocompletePredictions(String, LatLngBounds, AutocompleteFilter)
     * @see AutocompletePrediction#freeze()
     */
    private ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> getAutocomplete(CharSequence constraint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting autocomplete query for: " + constraint);

        // Submit the query to the autocomplete API and retrieve a PendingResult that will
        // contain the results when the query completes.
        Task<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse> results =
                mGeoDataClient.getAutocompletePredictions(constraint.toString(), mBounds,
                        mPlaceFilter);

        // This method should have been called off the main UI thread. Block and wait for at most
        // 60s for a result from the API.
        try {
            Tasks.await(results, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse autocompletePredictions = results.getResult();

            Log.i(TAG, "Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount()
                    + " predictions.");

            // Freeze the results immutable representation that can be stored safely.
            return DataBufferUtils.freezeAndClose(autocompletePredictions);
        } catch (RuntimeExecutionException e) {
            // If the query did not complete successfully return null
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error contacting API: " + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(TAG, "Error getting autocomplete prediction API call", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I am beginner so If you found any mistake then please point out. That would be great help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **Place Autocomplete** by google

> Step 1:-

Add a project in google developers account and get the key from there
https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=appsactivity&credential=client_key&pli=1

Example code

> Step 2:-

Add gradle

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.0'
```

or latest version

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:latest_version'
```

> Step 3:-

add this tag in manifest file

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="Your api key"/>
```

> Step 4:-

Now Implement your fragment or activity class with `PlaceSelectionListener` like this

```
public class Fragment_Profile extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, PlaceSelectionListener
```

declare this variable

```
private static final int REQUEST_SELECT_PLACE = 1000;
```

then finally on button click call this

```
try {
                    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                            .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES)
                            .build();
                    Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder
                            (PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                            .setFilter(typeFilter)
                            .build(getActivity());
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_PLACE);
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException |
                        GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

This is the filter you are looking for

> **AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES**

then in the overridden method get the selected value

```
 @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        Log.i("Selected", "Place Selected: " + place.getAddress());

    }
```

You can check the documentation from here
https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete
and
http://codesfor.in/android-places-autocomplete-example/

Thanks

Comment: thank you for answer, will implement when I go home. By the way google doesn't recommends using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-places` right?

Comment: thanks mate it worked :) you are great bro. And sorry for my previous comment google does recommends using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-places`

Comment: im really happy for you my dear, thats cool no worries , i dont think that will be a problem if you use it just saying i never faced any problem ever :)

Comment: Thank you and +1 for this awesome answer.

Comment: Thanks Brother @SaWin i appreciate that support , Cheers :)

Comment: can we able to search the location near by to particular latlong using PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/net/FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.Builder#public-abstract-latlng-getorigin

Comment: @khushbu try this

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields)
                        .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS)
                        .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.CITIES)
                        .setCountry("IN")
                        .build(SelectDistanceActivity.this);
                startActivityForResult(intent, Constant.AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);

//if you want to get city for specific country then use this line

//setCountry("IN")
```

Comment: please be include more details

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please include a summary of how your answer solves the problem and why it may be preferable to the other answer(s) provided.